# Cosmos DB change feed monitoring vs polling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have an image encoding service (asp.net core 5) and the pictures are processed via a queue, when the image is done all the image info are inserted into cosmos db.

I need to be notified when this append. It doesn't need to be at the same time it can have 1 second delay it would stile be acceptable.

So my question is: would it be better to process the cosmos db change feed to look for the insert event, or to poll via a query every second the id of the image to see if it exists?

Also I don't understand the cost around processing the change feed. If I poll the Id, it cost me around 3RU per query.

Any suggestion?

Comment: As you say "change stream" rather than "change feed" are you using MongoDB API?

Comment: If you are already using queues, why not just fire an message in another queue when the processing and upload is finished? Advantage: You also get the notifications when your app processing it is down for maintenance and can fetch it as soon as the app starts

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you I made an edit, I m using the SQL api and the .NET SDK

Comment: @Tseng that a good idea I will investigate this option too thank you

Comment: @Tseng - change feed processor certainly doesn't require the app to be always on to avoid missing events, as it stores bookmarks in a leases collection. I have been told that change streams also doesn't require this but haven't used it yet so not sure how that case is handled

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely use [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) here <s>with no additional cost (well, I might be wrong) than your write operation</s>. (EDIT: Change feed does incur some [additional RU consumption](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#change-feed-and-provisioned-throughput)). But problem with that is your feed listener would be notified only when something is written. So holistically you won't be able to track failure in your processing with this. A better approach can be just to send notification from your code at the end of processing logic (success or failure). You can also make async by sending a message to another queue and send notification from it's listener (another service).

Comment: consuming items from the change feed does also have an RU cost for the read. It is not "free". Practically though I tend to find that this is usually low compared to RU for other activities in the database and  can mostly be ignored - and there is also some (usually small) cost needed for the leases collection

Comment: Change Feed consumes 2 RU/s each second when it polls the leases container for new items. Then it consumes another 1 RU/s for 1Kb item or less it reads in.

Comment: Thank you @MarkBrown do you have a link to the documentation for that?

Comment: Documented here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#change-feed-and-provisioned-throughput. The amount isn't directly called out but the 2 RU/s I mention is per each instance.